# convert 8 bit binary vector to 1 grayscale pixel

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I am having binary vector of size 8 ie 8 bit vector of 1 and 0. How can I convert 8 bit vector to 1 bit grayscale pixel in python?

Comment: is it a numpy vector?

Comment: yes it is a numpy vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v = numpy.array([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])
g = numpy.sum(2**numpy.arange(8)*v)
```

For each bit we determine its weight by taking 2^0, 2^1 etc. we then take the product of the weight vector with our bit vector, and sum the values.

This assumes the first bit to be the least significant one, by reversing the range it could be the other way around:

```
g = numpy.sum(2**numpy.arange(7,-1,-1)*v)
```

both of these give you a greyscale value in the range 0-255. If you'd like to make this 1 bit, you could threshold it:

```
g = 1 if (numpy.sum(2**numpy.arange(7,-1,-1)*v) > 127) else 0
```

Comment: I am having vector [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.] and it shows false when I set the threshold > 127. What does this mean as I am not able to understand the output.

Comment: True == 1 and False == 0, i've updated the example to actually show 0 and 1

Comment: so in this case it will never be >127 as all the bits are 0 and 1. so the output will be always false. Does this mean I will not be able to create a greyscale pixel?

Comment: Sure you can. Just take one of the first two examples instead, that will give you an answer between 0-255. If you'd like it to be between 0-1, just scale it by dividing by 255

Comment: In my case, every time the array will be having maximum zero and fewer 1  for example [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0].  So it will be never >127. so that case what should I do?

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood your question. Could you update your question by illustrating it with some example vectors and the desired outputs (and how you got those outputs)?

Comment: I am having a binary vector of 512 dimensions. I need to convert this vector to 8*8 image and for that I need to process each 8 bit to greyscale pixel. First I reshaped 512 to 64*8 matrix so that each row can have 8 bit. Now I want to convert each of the 64 row to greyscale pixel. The problem is there will be no chance that result of each row after processing as you suggested can be greater then 127. so how can I convert 8 bit of vector to greyscale pixel.  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.] this are the vectors.